# Using One-to-Many Associations for the Public Activity Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, public-activity

I just started using the [PublicActivity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem and wanted to display the activities of authors throughout the site. In the app an **author** has many **books**. When an author releases a new book I'd like there to be a notification to appear in the feed's of **users**. Trying my best to translate what's shown in the code [example](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity#set-owner-and-recipient-based-on-associations) here's what I've come up with so far:

**Models**

```
class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: :author, recipient: :reader

  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "Author"
  belongs_to :reader, :class_name => "User"
end
```

**Activities Controller**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.all
  end
end
```

**Activities Index View**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= activity.inspect %> # Using inspect for now to debug
<% end %>
```

For now in the console I'm creating and appending books to an author (`author` being the instance variable) as so:

```
author.books << Book.create(name: "Jaws")
```

Activities are being recorded but the `owner_id` and `recipient_id` are nil when in reality the owner should be the author and the recipient should be the user.

```
#<PublicActivity::Activity id: 1, trackable_id: 1, trackable_type: "Book", owner_id: nil, owner_type: nil, key: "book.create", parameters: {}, recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2015-04-01 17:36:18", updated_at: "2015-04-01 17:36:18">
```

Comment: so recipient is like `current_user`?

Comment: anyways the line should be `author.books.create(name: 'Jaws')` so that the new books will contain the author's id

Comment: Yeah the recipient would be `current_user`.  When I ran that command though the owner id was still nil.

Comment: if it's the same link then for some reason author is an instance of book.

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally removed the association in the book model. But with that the owner_id was still nil.

Comment: what does `Book.last` show ?

Comment: Scratch that last comment. `owner_id` now shows the author! I'm assuming that `current_user` should be used for recipient? I'm using the gem, devise btw.

Comment: if that's the logic then yes, it would be something like this `author.books.create(name: 'Jaws', reader: current_user)`, donno if this matches your logic or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74291/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-mohammad-abushady).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the author you better use the relation while creating the new book

```
author.books.create(name: "Jaws")
```

Then if you want to save the reader, you'll need to add it in the args hash

```
author.books.create(name: "Jaws", reader: some_user)
```

**Note:**
The reason why this prefills the object is that when you call new on an active record relation object, all the conditions inside the condition are used to create the new object, for example

```
Book.where(author: some_author).new
```

This will generate an instance of book and the `author_id` will be the id of the `some_author` from the where query.

So when we did an `author.books` this created a query

```
Book.where(author_id: author.id)
```

And by calling new, the new book will have the id of the author.

**PS:**
This also works on multiple args in the `where`

```
Model.where(key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3).new
```

will create a new instance where the attributes `key1`, `key2`, `key3` are already filled.